# Proof that $\sqrt{\det(XY)^2} \leq \sqrt{\det(Y^TY)\det(XX^T)}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Proof that $\sqrt{\det(XY)^2} \leq \sqrt{\det(Y^TY)\det(XX^T)}$? I feel like I could use Cauchy-Binet here but I'm unsure of how to do so. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only non-trivial case where the products are well defined is where $X$ is $m \times n$ and $Y$ is $n \times m$ with $m \leq n$. We can prove that this formula holds by combining the [Cauchy-Binet formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula) with the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality). In particular, in the notation of the [CB formula wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula), we have
$$
\begin{align}
\det(XY)^2 &= \left(\sum_{S \in \binom{[n]}{m}}\det(X_{[m],S})\det(Y_{S,[m]})\right)^2
\\ & \leq \left(\sum_{S \in \binom{[n]}{m}}\det(X_{[m],S})^2\right)\left(\sum_{S \in \binom{[n]}{m}}\det(Y_{S,[m]})^2\right)
\\ & = \left(\sum_{S \in \binom{[n]}{m}}\det(X_{[m],S})\det(X^T_{S,[m]})\right)\left(\sum_{S \in \binom{[n]}{m}}\det(Y^T_{[m],S})\det(Y_{S,[m]})\right)
\\ &= \det(XX^T) \det(Y^TY),
\end{align}
$$
which was what we wanted.